# Stanford NLP Dependency parsing scenario

Tags: stanford-nlp

I have couple of sentences like below and for both the sentences i need to identify that XYZ JOB Failed.

Sentence 1: When running xyz job we are facing a failure

Sentence 2: We are facing failure when running xyz job

Dependency parser results are little different as the syntactic structure is different. Should we go for semantic role labelling for this or is there a way to identify this using Stanford Dependency parser

Answer (score 1):

You might get different results with a different parser, but when I parse these two sentences to Universal Dependencies using https://corenlp.run, then the two parses are exactly the same (except for the word order of course).

[image: Dependency parses]

In both cases, the averbial clause *When running xyz job* is attached to the main verb, *facing*, with an *advcl* relation and the internal structure of the two clauses is also the same in both parses.